# Convert SQL statement to Linq-2-Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How do I translate the following SQL statement into L2S?

```
SELECT DefaultCode, MAX(EffectiveDt) AS EffectiveDt
FROM tblDF_DefaultSetting
GROUP BY DefaultCode
```

Comment: Is that query complete?  There's an unmatched close parenthesis in there.

Comment: This raises and interesting question: is there a way to go from SQL to an Expression tree to LINQ Lambdas or LINQ queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `GroupBy` operator on `DefaultCode` and use the `Select` operator to create a new anonymous type with the two values you're interested in.

```
dataContext.tblDF_DefaultSetting
    .GroupBy(x => x.DefaultCode)
    .Select(x => new { DefaultCode = x.Key, EffectiveDt = x.Max(x => x.EffectiveDt) });
```